# Combining geom_text with substitute doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, geom-text

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(X = c(9.8186734, 19.6373468, 29.4560202, 39.2746936, 
49.093367, 58.9120404, 68.7307138, 78.5493872, 88.3680606, 98.186734
), Y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), radii = c(530.595715856625, 
530.595715856625, 524.270569515141, 520.785212389348, 524.423046929159, 
524.777454042683, 523.089321742221, 522.852371975715, 523.124870390148, 
522.612174462367), slope = c(-21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, 
-21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, 
-21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, -21.796356958782, -21.796356958782
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f989f011ce0>, sorted = "Y")
```

and I am simply trying to print `slope` as a text to the figure as

```
str_slope <- c(substitute("Slope = "~sp~mu*"m/s", list(sp = sprintf("%2.1f", dt[!duplicated(slope), slope]))))
d_text <- data.table(x=2000, y=500, label = str_slope)
ggplot(dt, aes(x = X, y=radii)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", level = 0.9999, se = TRUE)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = getPalette) +
  labs(x = "time (s)", y = expression("radius ["*mu*"m]"), color = "Speed [µm/s]") +
  geom_text(data = d_text, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label))+
  theme_default(legend.position = "none")
```

but I get something like this

[image]

Why is the text in `str_slope` not evaluated as an expression? How can I force ggplot to interpret it as an expression, so that the text will look like [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of plot annotation, you should use `annotate(geom="text"...)` rather than `geom_text()`.  For how to generate the expression, you can use the `parse=TRUE` argument within `annotate()`.

I think we're missing all your plot data, so here's an example with `mtcars` that incorporates the contents of `str_slope` in your example.

```
str_slope <- c(substitute("Slope = "~sp~mu*"m/s", list(sp = sprintf("%2.1f", dt[!duplicated(slope), slope]))))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

p + annotate(
  "text", x=4, y=25,
  label= str_slope, parse=TRUE)
```

[image]

For your information, `geom_text()` is designed to be used wherein one or more aesthetics are mapped to a data frame.  If you have only one line of text you want to appear on the plot, you should use `annotate(geom="text"...)`, which is used when you *do not* want to map any aesthetics to a data frame.